# vivado: how to view "pin assignments report" after generating FPGA bitstream?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, xilinx, vivado

Basically, this problem is related to mapping the toplevel IO's of either verilog or vhdl to the unused pins of a Xilinx FPGA.

Xilinx's old FPGA compiler, "ISE", used to give you a report of the "pin assignments" that the compiler was able to map to the bitfile, once the compiler was finished generating the FPGA binary file for upload.

However, with Xilinx's Vivado FPGA compiler, I have no idea where this report is located...

Does anybody know where to find the report or what the FPGA compiler actually mapped to the pins of the FPGA after finishing the compilation?

Basically, I want to see that Vivado accepted the IO's that I listed in the Xilinx Constraint file and was able to finishing mapping them to the FPGA pins in the Compiler output bitsteam file.

Comment: Actually, the IO mapping is done during Synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't warnings or errors relative to your pins after generating bitstream, Vivado has accepted your pinout.

You can have a view of your pins in Vivado :
 - Open your implemented design via the left panel
 - Layout -> IO planning (on the top bar)

[image]